# Who hosts and maintains Stellar Horizon server?

Tags: horizon, network, server

I'm thinking of developing apps on one of the Dapp platforms. When I skimmed through the Stellar doc, it seems the entry point to the network is the [Stellar Horizon RESTful server](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/).

According to the page I linked, the Horizon server connects to the Stellar Core, but it doesn't mention who owns the Horizon server.

If this is owned by Stellar dev team, then isn't it a single point of failure? If all dapps talk to the network through Horizon server, then once Horizon server is down, everything else will go down.

Answer (score 3):

Horizon server talks to Stellar core, and anyone can host stellar core and Horizon server. There are many core servers running they are like nodes on Stellar network, so there is no single point of failure. You can always host your own Stellar core and Horizon for a good network support and a better uptime for your dapp.
You can see the network states, nodes here - https://stellarbeat.io

Comment: Are there other Horizon hosts though? If not then they're the single entry point to communicate with the Stellar network right?

Comment: There are other Horizon hosts: all private. So you either use the stellar public one or your private one.